# Python Accessing a list form User input

Tags: python

I have some code here:

```
 cars = ['Blue car', 1],['Red car', 2],['Green car', 3]]
 user_input = input('Enter car number. ')
```

And when the user enters that car number, (say he entered 2), I want the program to print:

```
'you have chosen a red car'
```

I have tried using `print('You have chosen a' + cars[1][2])` but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: _but it doesn’t work_ What does that mean? Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: it comes with no nested list

Comment: Again, what does that mean?

Comment: Never mind I fixed it. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
print("You have chosen",cars[user_input-1][0])
```

The mistakes you made
1>List indexes start from 0
2>You should use the user-input
But a better solution would be a dictionary like this

```
dic = {1:"Blue Car,2:"Red Car"}
user_input = input("Enter number")
print("You have chosen a",dic[user_input]")
```

Answer (score 1):

since you are using a unique number to identify a car, it would be better if you use `dictionary` instead of list like

```
car = {1:"blue car", 2:"red car", 3:"green car"}
```

and when you take input from user as `user_input = int(input("Enter a car number"))`

then it become efficient to search for car in `O(1) time complexity` and you can use print as

```
 if user_input in car:
     print("You have chosen a {}".format(car[user_input]))
 else:
      print("invalid car number")
```

with the current code, first you need to convert the user input from string type to int type as car number are stored in int type and then using loop you need to find the element and show result.

```
 cars = ['Blue car', 1],['Red car', 2],['Green car', 3]]
 user_input = int(input('Enter car number. '))
 check = False
 for index, value in enumerate(cars):
     car, number = value
     if number == user_input:
          print(" you have chosen a {}".format(car))
          check = True
 if not check:
     print("invalid car number")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not access a dictionary like `car[user_input]`, because if key not exist it will give you a `KeyError`

You should always use `get(key_name)` method to access a dictionay value. Have a look in the below

```
car = {1:"blue car", 2:"red car", 3:"green car"}
user_input = input('Enter car number. ')
print(" you have chosen a {}".format(car.get(user_input )))
```

If key not exist, It will not give you an error, it will return `None` value